# JPA Eclipse link(MySQL)- Data not getting retrieved after successful write to Database

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I am using Eclipse Link JPA with Tomcat and MySQL. I keep the static object of Entity Manager as

```
em = factory.createEntityManager();
```

This Entity Manager is kept open through life of the application.
I do store entities using.

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(obj);
        em.flush();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
```

The entries are successfully written to MySQL and I can check them from MySQL console.
The problem is when I try to retrieve entries using.
em.find(MyType.class, id);
It returns nothing but if I restart tomcat then retreival works successfully. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you see the SQLs executed to the database? What is the Log output?

Comment: Yes, All the entries are made into SQL in the right way.

Comment: Could you provide the code for it? (reproducing the problem you reported)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the cause of your problem, but keeping a single EntityManager as a static variable inside a Web application is usually not a good idea, because EntityManager is not thread safe.  Instead, you should keep a static reference to an EntityManagerFactory and create an instance of EntityManager for each HTTP request (running in its own thread).

Comment: We are keeping locks to have the operations thread safe. Will creating EntityManager everytime will not lead to performance overhead.

Comment: No, that's how it is intended to be used. Here's an excerpt from the Hibernate doc (I assume it is the same for EclipseLink): "An EntityManager is an inexpensive, non-threadsafe object that should be used once, for a single business process, a single unit of work, and then discarded."